# Chopping A Line From A Text Document Into Different Strings

Tags: python, text, utf-8, io, python-3.x

I have a v. large text document (no file extension) that has information about a different file on every line in the following format:

```
VariableOne|VariableTwo|VaraibleThree
```

The pipe separates the different variables.
**However, within some 'VaraibleTwo's there may also be pipes.**

I need to extract that information from the text document so that I can manipulate the information. For example:

```
Name = VariableOne From The Text Document
Middle Name(s) = VariableTwo From The Text Document
Last Name = VariableThree From The Text Document
```

This needs to be done in *Python 3* with six variables all together and only the second variable containing pipes.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: So is it always true that everything up to the first pipe is VariableOne and everything from the last pipe to the end is VariableThree?

Comment: Yes.
To make things clearer there are six variables all together with only the second one able to contain pipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> s = 'a|b|more b|yet more b|c|d|e|f'
>>> a, *b, c, d, e, f = s.split('|')
>>> b = '|'.join(b)
>>> 
>>> a,b,c,d,e,f
('a', 'b|more b|yet more b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
```

where you could replace the explicit naming by slicing the split result, which might be a little more general.  As for reading the file, the usual pattern is

```
with open('somefile') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        a, *b, c, d, e, f = line.strip().split('|')
        b = '|'.join(b)
        # do something
```

which doesn't read the entire file into memory at once, which is handy for large files.

UPDATE: if you have to loop over all the lines, but only process one, then you could use

```
with open('somefile') as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):
        if i == some_number:
            a, *b, c, d, e, f = line.strip().split('|')
            b = '|'.join(b)
```

On the other hand, if there's only one line you need to extract and process, you can use the [linecache module:](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/linecache.html)

```
def proc(filename, lineno):
    line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno)
    a, *b, c, d, e, f = line.strip().split('|')
    b = '|'.join(b)
    # do something
```

Although to be honest, I think I prefer Karl Knechtel's two-argument split approach because it's more general.

Comment: That works perfectly.
Slightly off topic: I need to put this in a function which is fed the line number. How can I do this so that only the line requested has the chopping done to it and not every line?
Thank!

Answer (score 2):

See [Python string methods](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods). Specifically `index` and `rindex` should get you what you want:

```
line = 'first|middle|||stuff|end'

first_pipe = line.index('|')
last_pipe = line.rindex('|')

first = line[:first_pipe]
middle = line[first_pipe+1:last_pipe]
last = line[last_pipe+1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.split` takes an optional parameter for the maximum number of splits to perform. There is also `str.rsplit`, which is the same but "splits" backwards (which only makes a difference if you are setting a limit on the number of splits to perform).

We have 6 values, and the second may contain the delimiters; thus, we want to split 1 off the front, and 4 off the back.

```
a, rest = data.split('|', 1)
b, c, d, e, f = rest.rsplit('|', 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`str.partition()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) function:

```
var1, pipe, _ = line.partition('|')
_, pipe, var3 = line.rpartition('|')
var2 = line[len(var1+pipe):-len(var3+pipe)]
```

[example](http://ideone.com/nj7SI).

Or using regular expressions:

```
import re

m = re.match(r'^([^|]*)\|(.*)\|([^|]*)$', line)
```

[example](http://ideone.com/oU98l).